# Scala, Adding 2d arrays to a 3d array

Tags: arrays, scala, concatenation

im trying to add 2d elements to a 3d array in scala.

i have these 4 arrays   [[,]] & [9,2] & [3,1] & [0,9]

i want [[9,2],[3,1],[0,9]]    < essentially turn my 3d array into a list of the 2d ones.

```
import Array._

object thing1 {


var list_of_lists = Array():Array[Array[Int]]
var list_1 = Array(9,2)
var list_2 = Array(3,1)
var list_3 = Array(0,9)
println("lllll")
list_of_lists ++ Array(list_1(0),list_1(1));  // nope          although i get an error here saying illegal start of simple expression
list_of_lists ++ list_2;   // nope 
list_of_lists = concat(list_of_lists, list_1) // also nope 
println(list_of_lists(0)(0) + "          this should be 9")
println("lllll")
}
```

Comment: You said that you want to add `2d` Arrays to a `3d` array. But the code show adding `1d` Arrays to a `2d`. Second, appending elements to an array is pretty inefficient, maybe it would be better to reserve all the positions you would need and then fill the array. Finally, what exactly do you want to do here? What is the macro problem? There are probably better ways than Arrays and mutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiomatically you are probably after something like

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
List(Point(9, 2), Point(3, 2), Point(0, 9))
```

however here are some examples using `Array`:

```
val list_of_lists = new Array[Array[Int]](3)

val list_1 = Array(9,2)
val list_2 = Array(3,1)
val list_3 = Array(0,9)

list_of_lists(0) = list_1
list_of_lists(1) = list_2
list_of_lists(2) = list_3

assert(list_of_lists(0)(0) == 9)
```

or

```
val list_1 = Array(9,2)
val list_2 = Array(3,1)
val list_3 = Array(0,9)
assert(Array(list_1, list_2, list_3).apply(0)(0) == 9)
```

or

```
val list_1 = Array(9,2)
val list_2 = Array(3,1)
val list_3 = Array(0,9)
assert((Array[Array[Int]]() :+ list_1 :+ list_2 :+ list_3).apply(0)(0) == 9)
```